# How to store tiptap editor data in a php form?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, tiptap

I want to use the TipTap editor in a php form as a textarea field. I've created a Vue component and passed it to the blade view.

Blade view:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('dashboard.edit.postInfo', $garage) }}">
     @method('PATCH')
     @csrf

     <div id="app">
        <editor content='{{ $garage->description }}'></editor>
     </div>

     <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

My Vue Component:

```
<template>
<div class="editor">

    <div class="card p-2 mt-1">
        <editor-content :editor="editor" />
    </div>
    
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'


export default {
    name: "editor",
    components: {
        EditorContent,
        
    },
    props: [
        'content'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            
            editor: null,
    
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.editor = new Editor({
            content: this.content
        })
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        // Always destroy your editor instance when it's no longer needed
        this.editor.destroy()
    },
}
</script>
```

How can I do this? Thanks you in advance.

This is the console.Log output:

```
Editor {…}
   activeMarks: (...)
   activeNodes: (...)
   commands: (...)
   defaultOptions: (...)
   element: (...)
   options: Object
      autoFocus: (...)
      content: "<p>KFZ Meisterwerkstatt...</p>"
```

Some lorem ipsum text for posting

Answer (score 0):

Try this bind `:value="editor"`

```php
<div class="card p-2 mt-1">
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
    <input type="hidden" name="content" :value="editor">
</div>
```

then u will get `content` key in laravel with data

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221317/discussion-on-answer-by-kamlesh-paul-how-to-store-tiptap-editor-data-in-a-php-fo).